# Apt-Daemon problem due to a broken sun-java6-jre package

Tags: software-center

I am having problems with installation with everything in the software center.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 968, in simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the sun-java6-jre package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

Help?

Comment: I solved the problem

Comment: Marv, if you solved the problem, please do add it as an answer so we can upvote the answer and mark this question as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove sun-java6-bin
```

The problem was caused by an incomplete installation of JDK6

For anyone having this problem, I recommend installing Synaptic Package Manager after fixing this to avoid any problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you should do:

```
sudo apt-get --configure -a 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I'm not sure but I think this might help...

Comment: I tried that. No worries. I solved it.

Comment: @Marv if Nikolas  helped you. It would be nice if you honour it otherwise please tell us how you solved this problem maybe it could help other people with similar problems. :-)

Comment: @tvn 2 more hours. =D