# Ubuntu Software Centre Issue (unity 11.10) after broken sun-java6-jre package installation

Tags: installation, command-line, java

I have been installing software packages from USC and I am getting the following error message.  Worked fine one minute then the message below. Tried to search but couldn't find a solution  Previously I was installing the sun-java6-jre package in terminal and had an connection outage and it didnt complete.  I attempted an apt-get -f install with no success. i dont know what to try next. I'm relatively new to Linux.  The answer provided with a similar question on this site didnt resolve the issue for me[Click on this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109793/apt-daemon-problem-due-to-a-broken-sun-java6-jre-package)

**An unhandlable error occured**
There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.

**Details**

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the sun-java6-jre package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.

Terminal Output Link
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48466855/Terminal%20output.odt

Comment: please add to your question the terminal output to the following: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: As requested: See output

Comment: ?? please put the results into your question or via pastebin.com

Comment: Thanks and apologies, Im new to this, I added a link from my dropbox but I will look at pastebin now

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kJ6BRPtF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - you are using a PPA that when installing producing the following screen.

[image]

I looks like you closed this screen unexpectedly causing the package manager issues.

Restart the package installation via

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

When you get to this screen, press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key or possibly the arrow keys to navigate to the OK button.  Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This will allow your installation to complete successfully.

Note - this is not the recommended method to install Java.

The links below will explain the community accepted Java installation methods.

If you follow this, then first clean up your installation by removing the PPA.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This should now report no more errors.

N.B. if you definitely want JRE 6 - just substitue the *1.7* reference with *1.6* in my answer.

---

Linked Question2:

1. [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)
2. [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

Comment: Thanks I entered the first line (Command not found)  http://pastebin.com/CAFyFDQz

Comment: Unfortunately still an issue: http://pastebin.com/sgk9Q92Y

Comment: when you do `sudo apt-get -f install` what is the output?

Comment: same error msg as my last paste, not our lucky night!

Comment: apt-get -f install has brought it to the sun-java8-bin Package configuration screen

Comment: This is the point i got to when losing the internet connection earlier. http://pastebin.com/LvfqNbNW.  It doing something but I cant see progress.

Comment: huh? can you imgur.com a screenshot?  Just to confirm - when you tried `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove sun-java6-bin` what happened?

Comment: http://imgur.com/rGuA7   and   http://imgur.com/IL7Aq

Comment: ... ooo .... on that first screenshot - press the tab key or the arrow keys to move to the OK button and press enter.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z5hUNsUV  when I tried sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove sun-java6-bin

Comment: **PROBLEM SOLVED** Thank you for all your help.  I will look at your answer above and purge then install Oracle